How to Deploy SSL certificate in React js?
I have generated root certificate and server certificate for ssl and added into chrome . My GUI application still not working on HTTPS . My code is in React js. DO I have to write code for https in react js file . Please let me know.
I have tried all possible ways to run GUI on https but not able to run my application.
I have to run curl call API it runs on HTTPS.
